# Javascript string concatenation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="#">{{ meeting.date }}</a>


$('.meet a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/meeting_display/" + txt;
    $("a").attr("href", url);
});
```

In the above function, I am trying to go to a url on click on the anchor element. 
But everytime, the value of **url** is "http://localhost:8000/meeting_display/%20*value of **txt** *

Thus I am not able to create a hyperlink to the intended page. Please help me.

Comment: `$.trim()` may solve it

Comment: Are you sure `txt` doesn't have an extra leading space?

Comment: `%20` is the url encoding for a space. `txt` therefore has to have an extra space that you need to remove as alex suggested.

Comment: what is the text format of your meeting date? is it 2016/03/10 for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alex said, use trim to remove blank space :

```
<a href="#">{{ meeting.date }}</a>


$('.meet a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    txtTrim = $.trim(txt);
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/meeting_display/" + txtTrim;
    $("a").attr("href", url);
});
```